# safe to kill multiple sftp.so processes?

Tags: debian, sftp

I have debian 10 and kde plasma. I have about 5 processes running named "sftp.so", and they are each using about 8% CPU. I searched on "sftp.so" and I couldn't find anything.

What are these processes?

Is it safe to kill them?

Comment: I have not used KDE in a while, but I vagely remember seeing this when I had SFTP connections open through Dolphin (file manager).

But your CPU usage is 8% per process is quite high unless you actually are actively using SFTP without realizing it. Did you try restarting the system or closing out the File Manager. If you do not use SFTP, may be you can remove the corresponding plugin from your file manager. Again from memory - the plugin may be called `fish`

Comment: I had a dolphin window open that was using an sftp connection, but I closed it. I went ahead and closed all the open dolphin windows, but the sftp processes are still there.

Comment: Well, I went ahead and /ended/ (not kill) those processes and it's still running, so I guess it didn't hurt anything.